# How do I "catch" a failed command that doesn't work with try...catch?

Tags: exchange-2010, powershell, powershell-v3.0

I'm running the following script that fails for a mailbox that doesn't exist

```
Set-MailboxDatabase rdb16 -AllowFileRestore:$true
Mount-Database rdb16
$stats = Get-MailboxStatistics -Database rdb16 
ForEach ($item in $stats)   {

try
{
get-mailbox -Identity $item.DisplayName | Set-Mailbox -Database rdb16 -Force
}
catch{
write-host "Create Mailbox:" 
}
}
```

Here is the failure

```
The operation couldn't be performed because object 'schmoe, joe' couldn't be found on 'NYCEXRESTOREDC0.sss.com'.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Mailbox], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CEA5387A,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.GetMailbox
```

How do I properly detect the error that is shown above, since it doesn't actually offer a "exception" style failure I'd expect in the C# world

Answer (score 4):

You are seeing this behavior because try/catch blocks only work on terminating errors ([MSDN Powershell Error Type Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms714414%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

You can manipulate the way Powershell works by changing the [$ErrorActionPreference](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/03/11/hey-scripting-guy-march-11-2010.aspx) Variable.

If you adjust your script to have `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` at the top, then all errors will be considered terminating errors, and the try/catch block will work.

If you just want the error action to be changed for one command you can use the `-ErrorAction` parameter to change it for that command.

Comment: Though true, the Exchange 2010 cmdlets do not seem to have implemented exceptions correctly. For instance -ErrorAction Stop does not cause the cmdlet to throw a terminating error. In my testing, I did find setting $ErrorActionPreference worked, however, as this is a global setting, I never recommend that it be changed, unless you really know what you are doing and set it back to its original value when done.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to 'catch' an error, I'll show you my example and maybe you can build on it.

```
function LoggedOnUser($MachineNameOrIP){

    $LoggedOnUser = "CouldNotGetUser"

    trap [Exception]{ # this installs an error handler for the function

        Write-Host "Error Accessing WMI - $MachineNameOrIP"
        Log("Error Accessing WMI - $MachineNameOrIP")

        continue;

    }


    $LoggedOnUser = Get-WMIObject Win32_Process -filter 'name="explorer.exe"' -computername $MachineNameOrIP |
    ForEach-Object { $owner = $_.GetOwner(); '{0}\{1}' -f $owner.Domain, $owner.User } |
    Sort-Object | Get-Unique

    return $LoggedOnUser
```

}

As you can probably guess, this is a function for finding the logged on user of a machine. There is a part in the middle for trapping any exceptions. You may be able to get away with

```
trap [ManagementObjectNotFoundException] {....}
```

As powershell ties .net in intimately.

Comment: Trapping "exception" didn't allow me to solve the problem I posted.  I tested it and it doesn't work.

Comment: the trap command falls under the same terminating/non-terminating constraints as try/catch